# Angular focus out event order with cdkMonitorSubtreeFocus

Tags: angular, focus, angular-cdk

Template of child-component:

```
<div>
  <input (focusout)="inputFocusOut()"/>
</div>
```

Template of parent component:

```
<div>
  <child-component 
cdkMonitorSubtreeFocus (cdkFocusChange)="$event === null && onChildFocusOut()"/>
</div>
```

I can see that `inputFocusOut()` gets called after `onChildFocusOut()`. Is there a way to make `inputFocusOut()` call happen before `onChildFocusOut()`?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `blur` + `EventEmitter` on child component and bind such event on parent?

Child template:

```html
<div>
  <input (blur)="onBlur()"/>
</div>
```

Child component:

```js
@Component()
class ChildComponent {
  @Output() blur = new EventEmitter();

  onBlur() {
    // do something here

    this.blur.emit();
  }
}
```

Parent Template:

```html
<div>
  <child-component (blur)="onChildBlur()" />
</div>
```

This way guarantee that child component do something before its parent.